# VS Code: long compilation time for React app

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, create-react-app

I use **Code-OSS** ("redefined" VS Code for Arch Linux).
Recently, confronted with problem  [**error ENOSPC**](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux#_visual-studio-code-is-unable-to-watch-for-file-changes-in-this-large-workspace-error-enospc). And solved with following  [instruction](https://gist.github.com/tbjgolden/c53ca37f3bc2fab8c930183310918c8c).

However, after this React projects' compiling time notably increased (>20 sec). I use **create-react-app**. Any suggestions?

**info:**

- Code-OSS version: 1.49.1-1
- Electron: 9.2.1
- Node.js: 12.14.1
- OS:Linux x645.8.16-2-MANJARO
- React: 17.0.1
- npm: 6.14.8